# Spring's WebClient hanging on bodyToMono(Pojo) with MockServer

Tags: java, spring, okhttp, spring-webflux

I want to mock an external API, which I am calling as part of my service. Therefore, I wanted to use the `MockWebServer` from okhttp3. My problem is that the call to `bodyToMono` works fine, if I want to retrieve the body as string, but does not work when retrieving it as data class. I tried to trim it down using the following code snippet:

```
public class MockWebClientTest {

    private MockWebServer server;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        server = new MockWebServer();
        server.start(9876);
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() throws IOException {
        server.shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    public void stringWorks() throws JsonProcessingException {
        createMockedTokenCall();

        Mono<String> response = WebClient.create(this.server.url("/").toString())
            .get()
            .uri("/")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);

        System.out.println(response.block());
    }

    @Test
    public void classDoesNotWork() {
        createMockedTokenCall();

        Mono<AuthToken> response = WebClient.create(this.server.url("/").toString())
            .get()
            .uri("/")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(AuthToken.class);

        System.out.println(response.block());
    }

    private void createMockedTokenCall() {
        server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("{\"accessToken\":\"BARBAR\",\"refreshToken\":\"FOOFOO\"}"));
    }
}

class AuthToken {
    private String accessToken;
    private String refreshToken;

    //constructor
}
```

The first Test (`stringWorks`) is working fine and return the correct json representation. However, the second test (`classDoesNotWork`) hangs forever on the `bodyToMono` call.

My guess is that it has nothing to do with the okttp3 library directly, since I had the same error using Wiremock. The same code works however when targeting a real API endpoint. Unfortunately, I could not find another way to test my calls using `WebClient` since Spring currently has no direct mocking support for it (see [SPR-15286](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15286)).

I am really looking forward to help on that matter! Thanks in advance!

General remark: This is basically a more or less copy of test case `shouldReceiveJsonAsPojo` in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webflux/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClientIntegrationTests.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after looking at the linked test and doing a bit of comparison, I found the solution (or my bug so to say): I forgot the correct `Content-Type` header. So it works using the following:

```
private void createMockedTokenCall() {
    server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).setBody("{\"accessToken\":\"BARBAR\",\"refreshToken\":\"FOOFOO\"}"));
}
```

Apart from me doing a mistake, I really think that this should not result in an infinite hanging of the application...